# How to automatically generate documentation for Web API Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have some Asp.net MVC Controller that act as Web API. However, something like Swagger, only generates API document from the Controller that inherits System.Web.Http.ApiController (based on IApiExplore I think?). Is there a way that I can configure so that I can generate API documentation from the normal Controller?

Comment: Why not add a Web API controller to your project instead?

Comment: @KennethK.Well it's a legacy project with quite a number of controllers, with stuff like JsonRequestBehavior... so I don't want to change all of it to the Web API controller (We also do not have automatic regression test so it's not very straightforward to made these changes).

Answer (score 1):

I started with this project and modified it to generate some sample json for a project. It reads the classes using reflection and generates HTML pages. Just code the HTML output to be what you want. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-time-help-page-3048fb43